# Why some audio files are not accessible on API level 30 with scoped storage?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-external-storage, android-internal-storage, scoped-storage

I have the following code to fetch all the `OPUS` audio files and it works well for all the files except one directory i.e, `WhatsApp Voice Notes`. Although audio files under `WhatsApp Audio` are fetched successfully. Is there any restriction/permission I am missing to access the files inside `WhatsApp Voice Notes`?

```
private  fun readAllOpusFiles() {
    val resolver = this.contentResolver
    val uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED)
    val cursor = resolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null, null)
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            val id = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
            val name = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
            var path = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH)
            Log.d("File ID: ", cursor.getString(id))
            Log.d("File Name: ", cursor.getString(name))
            if (cursor.getString(path) != null) {
                Log.d("File Path: ", cursor.getString(path))
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext())
    }
}
```

PS: At Android 10 and prior, I can access all the files using `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in manifest and below `uri` by looping `listFiles` on `file`,

```
val uri = URI.create("file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Voice%20Notes")
val file = File(uri)
```

Comment: Please tell full path of those whatsapp directories.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#other-app-specific-dirs

Comment: `Is there any restriction/permission I am missing to access the files inside WhatsApp Voice Notes?` What do you mean exactly? Are they listed by your code but you cannot access them? Or are they not listed at all?

Comment: That full path will be `/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Voice Notes` instead.

Comment: did you add this tag android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" and whats your target SDK ?

Comment: @Quicklearner `minSdkVersion 26` & `targetSdkVersion 30`. For API Level 30, this tag doesn't matter. It works on 29 and below.

Comment: `but why can I access from the WhatsApp Audio directory as both directories are at same level under WhatsApp` Well.. you will not have replaced all "%20" by " " first as i showed you already.

Comment: @blackapps, Don't worry about those. As you haven't tried creating URI from plain string(with spaces) so its handled by the URI itself to understand what those characters mean. As I mentioned in the question I have no problem accessing all the files prior to API 30 so this has nothing to do with the problem. Also the code I'm using to access the files inside `readAllOpusFiles` method has no use of path so it's out of question.

Comment: You are not accessing files in that function but querying the mediastore. And you did not answer my question. Repeat: `Are they listed by your code but you cannot access them? Or are they not listed at all?.`

Answer (score 2):

The restriction is related to the presence of `.nomedia` file in the directory /WhatsApp Voice Notes/